# Conversion of Riemann sum into definite integral

Tags: integration

> [image]

I was trying to do this but I dont know how to put convert it into a definite integral also I got confused about limits of the integral now im stuck.

Answer (score 1):

For an integral between zero and one you can take the partition
$$ 0 = 0 < \frac{1}{n} < \frac{2}{n} < \dots < \frac{n}{n} = 1.$$
Then the integral over $f(x)$ from zero to one becomes
$$ \int_0^1 f(x) dx = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{n} f\left(\frac{k}{n}\right).$$
Here first rewrite
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(2n+5k)^2}{n^3} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{n} \left(2+ 5 \frac{k}{n}\right)^2,$$
now you can read of $f(x)$ and evaluate the integral $\int_0^1 f(x) \,dx$ to find the value of the sum.